# "The creator of this list has upgraded these reminders" - macOS Catalina beta vs. iOS 12 Reminder incompatibility

Tags: reminders, beta-seed-program, catalina

After installing Catalina (10.15 Beta (19A487m))on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) Reminders no longer sync across devices (e.g., between the Reminders app on a Mac running the Catalina beta and the Reminders app on an iPhone running iOS 12.3.1).

On the iPhone there are new reminders items suggesting that something needs to be done, including one titled "The creator of this list has upgraded these reminders" with a note that reads "Learn more here: [kb article link]" - but there is no link - this looks to me like a beta loose end, and I assume that it will be resolved in a future release.

What I'm wondering right now is if anyone has found a way to get reminders working - would installing the iOS 13 beta on the iPhone get reminders working (and get me some new "quirks")? Or is there an updated version of the iOS 12 app?

Comment: Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.  You'll need to [edit] your question to include the relevant info regarding version/build and hardware type.  Also, be sure you've opened a Feedback to Apple about this issue.

Comment: Does the beta-seed-program tag apply to the public betas? Feedback filed, but not expecting a response :-)

Comment: Yes, it applies to all beta programs here.  The most important thing is filing the Feedback.  Make sure you add the beta version & build info (for all beta software you're using) to your question.